# converting a blob (.bacpac) to .bacpac file to import database to SQL Server Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

While working in MVC/ C# with Azure I need to restore database from a .bacpac file which is stored in blob storage. I m using DAC Framework API to access .bacpac from Blob storage.

Issue:

`DacServices.ImportBacpac` requires .bacpac file, I am able to refer blob file (which is a .bacpac) but it comes as a blob and not as a .bacpac file. I m not sure how to convert a blob to a .bacpac. Can you please guide me some way or API to do that conversion ? 
Later I will use this file to import backpac to SQL Server Azure.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is probably to read the blob as a stream (CloudBlob.DownloadToStream()) and create the bacpac from said stream (BacPackage.Load()).

Comment: Maybe you can answer this as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409710/error-restoring-database-to-server-net-core-should-not-be-using-a-file-backed