# Is it possible to programmatically restore bacpac/bak from blob storage into azure sql with C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

Is it possible to somehow create an azure function which will restore an azure sql database whenever a new bacpac/bak file is created in the blob storage?

Comment: this looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464034/converting-a-blob-bacpac-to-bacpac-file-to-import-database-to-sql-server-azu?rq=1, probably if you create a blob trigger and use the DacServices.ImportBacpac() it should work.

Comment: you can also use the Azure REST api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases%20-%20import%20export/createimportoperation

Comment: Thanks, guys. Looks like the first solution with DacServices works!

Comment: @TamásHuj please consider posting this as an answer so people can upvote/mark as verified.

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT ok, I did it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an azure function with a blob trigger and in your C# code you can us the `DacServices.ImportBacpac` method. Here is a similar question: [converting a blob (.bacpac) to .bacpac file to import database to SQL Server Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464034/converting-a-blob-bacpac-to-bacpac-file-to-import-database-to-sql-server-azu?rq=1)

And here is the MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacservices.importbacpac?view=sql-dacfx-140.3881.1

As an alternative solution you can also make an Azure REST API call. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases%20-%20import%20export/createimportoperation
"Creates an import operation that imports a bacpac into an existing database. The existing database must be empty."

Comment: Maybe you can answer this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311105/creating-azure-db-with-huge-backpac-files