# create a database from a copy C# application using Azure Sql

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to figure out the best way to create a database from a copy of a database.

The C# application has the user register to become a user of the website and once the registration is approved then it needs to look at the Main database and create a direct copy of it. So for this example, MainDB(name of the main database) has all of the schema needed to create a copy for the user. So when the user registers it would create UserDB (name of the copy database for user).

Right now I am doing this by the below code,

```
        SqlConnection cn;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataReader dataReader;

            cn.Open();
            string dbName = UserDB;
            command = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE " + dbName + " AS COPY OF MainDB", cn);
            command.CommandTimeout = 120;
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            cn.Close();
```

This is working, but it is so unpredictable on how much time it takes to populate in azure, that I can not figure out a reasonable amount of time to wait before a timeout and throwing an error when creating a user for the new database.

I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this for a C# application. Possibly importing a bacpac file of the database into an Azure Data Factory, and creating the database from there? But I have not been able to find an example of this to run code using a C# application. I have just read that it reads faster, not sure if true.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is this helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464034/converting-a-blob-bacpac-to-bacpac-file-to-import-database-to-sql-server-azu?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if recovering a database from bacpac will be significantly faster. But the time spread required for recovery should be less.

The following C # code will import the database:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac;

var services = new DacServices (connectionString);    
services.ImportBacpac (BacPackage.Load (fileName), restoredDatabaseName, cancellationToken);
```

Please note that the restored database will be restored at the default price tier. This can be very important if you are restoring several small databases, each of them will consume ~ 450 $.

With the help of the following sql command you can find out in what price tier the original database was.

```
SELECT
    s.edition as [Edition],
    s.service_objective as [ServiceObjective],
    s.elastic_pool_name as [ElasticPoolName]
FROM
    sys.databases d
        JOIN sys.database_service_objectives s
            ON d.database_id = s.database_id
WHERE d.Name = @dbName
```

After importing the .bacpac, install the edition for the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE [@dbName] MODIFY (EDITION = @ edition, SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = @ ServiceObjective)
```

or elastic pool:

```
ALTER DATABASE [@dbName] MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL (name = [@elastic_pool_name]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue after looking at the code , you are creating a USERDB and want to have the schema and the data in the USERDB  from MASTERDB .

Well you can use a bacpac file ,  bacpac file is simply a ZIP file with the data for each schema . If I were you , I could have copied the files to a blob and let ADF copy the data to the USERDB . The advantage of doing this way is that we can implement parallelism in the copy activity and the USERDB is will be ready sooner .

Answer (score 0):

How up to date does the UserDB have to be?  I ask because if the performance is that unpredictable and responding immediately is important you’d consider running it in the background ahead of time so you have a recent DB you can use on standby.

Also is it the schema AND the data?  Because if it’s just the schema then copying whole database seems like overkill.

How big is the database right now?  Bacpac files work well for small databases, but once you’re in the range of a few hundred GB good luck

Happy to look further into this